# Contact display name is not get edited in Android

Tags: android, android-contacts, contacts

I am trying to Edit Specific Contact's display name, but whatever I do, display name is not getting edited. I have looked all related questions, but I did not find any solution regarding this issue.

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
    .withSelection(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " +
                   ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.MIMETYPE + "='" +
                   ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "' AND "+ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.RAW_CONTACT_ID +"=?",
            new String[]{id,raw})
    //.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, "B "+name)
    //.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHONETIC_NAME, "B "+name)
    //.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY, "B "+name)
    //.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME, "B "+name)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, "B "+name)
    .build());
try {
    ContentProviderResult[] result =HomeActivity.this.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    Log.e("Edit Result",result.toString());
} catch (RemoteException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have tried all option which are written in comments, but with `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME`. It edits contact No. instead of contact name. I am trying to do this for the last 3 days, but not getting success. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong or show me the right way of editing contact name.

Answer (score 0):

The name is stored in contacts database with STRUCTURED_NAME mime type. [More information here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.html)

You should modify your code like this

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
    .withSelection(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " +
                   ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.MIMETYPE + "='" +
                   ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName + "' AND "+ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.RAW_CONTACT_ID +"=?",
            new String[]{id,raw})
    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, "B "+name)
    .build());
try {
    ContentProviderResult[] result =HomeActivity.this.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    Log.e("Edit Result",result.toString());
} catch (RemoteException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I would suggest that you pull out the contacts database from an emulator or a rooted phone to get a better understanding.